# How to have the same image for different img elements widths without losing quality?

Tags: html, image, responsive-images, srcset

I have the same image at multiple widths, e.g. `balloon-35.webp`, `balloon-40.webp`, `balloon-90.webp`.

I also have multiple `img` elements with different widths, e.g. `<img width="35"/>`, `<img width="40"/>`, `<img width="90"/>`.

Can I specify the `srcset` attribute for each `img` with the 3 files mentionned above and have the `img` element chose the right file according to the `width` attribute? For example, if the width of the `img` is 35, then the 35 file is chosen.

Or is my only option to change the `src` attribute with the right file depending on the width? Or is there another way to achieve what I want?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the snippet code, i have design for you just enter the images URL in the array of images as mention **imagesUrls = ['balloon-35.webp', 'balloon-40.webp', 'balloon-90.webp'];**. Value of url should be anything just the last 7 character **40.webp** etc should be same as you mention in your upper description.

```js
var a = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

function stups(){

  var tagWidth = a[0].getAttribute("width");
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = tagWidth;
  console.log(tagWidth);
var src = "";
var imagesUrls = ['balloon-35.webp', 'balloon-40.webp', 'balloon-90.webp'];

for (var img of imagesUrls)
 {
var width = img.substr(img.length - 7);
var widthValue = width.substring(0, 2);
if (tagWidth.substring(0, 2) === widthValue){
  src = img;
 }
}
console.log(src);
document.getElementById("imageClass").src = src;
}
```

```html
<BUTTON ONCLICK="stups()">VALUE FINDER </BUTTON>
<a value="this is a value" width="35px" href="value"><img id="imageClass" src=""> values rule!!</a>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Do Ping me up, If you think that i did something good for you. Cheers!